# Angular 2 - Typescript: TS2322: Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'Observable<MouseEvent>'

Tags: angular, typescript, mouseevent, rxjs, observable

I am using the click-outside directive from this plunk --> http://embed.plnkr.co/v7BMUv/

My TS compiler is throwing the following errors:

TS2322: Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'Observable'.
  Property '_isScalar' is missing in type 'Subscription'.

TS2339  Property 'unsubscribe' does not exist on type 'Observable'.

My tsconfig.json:

```js
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

The code causing error:

```js
  ngOnInit() {
    this.globalClick = Observable
      .fromEvent(document, 'click')
      .delay(1)
      .do(() => {
        this.listening = true;
      }).subscribe((event:MouseEvent) => {
        this.onGlobalClick(event);
      });
  }
```

How do I overcome this error?

Comment: This error is related to static code analysis by TypeScript. Paste the code causing this error.

Comment: Edited to add the code

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error is in `click-outside.directive.ts`. `Observable.subscribe` returns a `Subscription` (in `ngOnInit`), not another `Observable`. Thus, the type of `private globalClick` should be `Subscription`.

It works when types are removed, and as plunker doesn't show type errors it worked, but when compiling with `tsc` it will error out as you're trying to assign a `Subscription` object to an `Observable`.