# How to detect if user clicked on that div?

Tags: angular

What i want is to check if user clicked anywhere in specific div. If not do something. I tried this:

```
handleClick(event){
        var clickedComponent = event.target;
        console.log(event.target,'adsadasdas');
        var inside = false;
        do {
            if (clickedComponent === this._eref.nativeElement) {
                inside = true;
            }
            clickedComponent = clickedComponent.parentNode;
        } while (clickedComponent);
        if(inside){
            console.log('inside');
        }else{
            console.log('outside');
        }
    }
```

Problem with this is that i have `*ngIf` on some elements so event.target is sometime false. So now i added a wrapper around and i want to check if user clicked inside that wrapper.

Comment: add a click event on the div ?

Comment: but when user click outside that div, how to detect that?

Comment: add a click event on the whole page ?

Comment: added a answer @None a directive will help

Comment: @Pac0 i cannot add event on whole page because that div is inside that whole page if i click will trigger always that event then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why you just use in the view the following?

```
<div *ngIf="cond" (click)="myEventHandler"></div>
```

and in the controler

```
myEventHandler(){
//do something
}
```

Comment: yes but what if i click outside that div ?? how to handle that if i click handler on that component

Comment: <div (click)="onClick($event)" id="div2">Click</div>
    <div (click)="onClick($event)" id="div1">Click</div>

  onClick(event) {
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement || event.currentTarget;
    var idAttr = target.attributes.id;
    var value = idAttr.nodeValue;
if(value =="div1"){
//do something
}else{
//do something
}
}

Answer (score 4):

Look at this Directive credits to - https://christianliebel.com/2016/05/angular-2-a-simple-click-outside-directive/

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, Output, EventEmitter, HostListener} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[clickOutside]'
})
export class ClickOutsideDirective {
    constructor(private _elementRef : ElementRef) {
    }

    @Output()
    public clickOutside = new EventEmitter();

    @HostListener('document:click', ['$event.target'])
    public onClick(targetElement) {
        const clickedInside = this._elementRef.nativeElement.contains(targetElement);
        if (!clickedInside) {
            this.clickOutside.emit(null);
        }
    }
}
```

Also Look at this [**plunker**](http://embed.plnkr.co/v7BMUv/)

**Update**

```
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
```

Comment: im getting an error for this directive: Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'Observable<MouseEvent>'.
  Property '_isScalar' is missing in type 'Subscription'.

Comment: u need to add import for subscription with rxjs

Comment: i added this directive but i get false again even if i clicked on some component inside div

Comment: Please check the plunker too

Comment: yes but i have inside my wrapper multiple components with ngIf that are on some moment hidden and i get value true like it is clicked outside but it wasnt

Comment: regarding the plunker maybe you should update the type of globalClick which should be a Subscription according to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41264465/angular-2-typescript-ts2322-type-subscription-is-not-assignable-to-type-o